# Вывести id кнопки в поле параграфа

Tags: vue.js

После нажатия на кнопку нужно вывести его значение ("123") в поле параграфа.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
   val(){
    return this.id
    }
  }
})
```

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 250px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button id="123" @click="val">button</button>
  <p v-html="val()"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      value: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getVal(){
      this.value = this.$refs.button.getAttribute('id');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 250px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button ref="button" id="123" @click="getVal">button</button>
  <p>{{value}}</p>
</div>
```